# Como passar dados para a view automaticamente no Laravel Resource Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.6 com Resource Controller. Meu método show:

```
public function show(Artigo $artigo)
{
    $artigo = $artigo->first();
    return view('painel.revista.detalhes', compact('artigo'));
}
```

Seria possível ignorar a linha `$artigo = $artigo->first();` e passar a variável diretamente para a view? Tentei:

```
public function show(Artigo $artigo)
{
    return view('painel.revista.detalhes', compact('artigo'));
}
```

Porém, não consegui acessar os dados na view, tentei: `{{ $artigo->titulo }}` mas não funcionou.

A collection Artigo foi incluída como parâmetro ao rodar:

```
php artisan make:controller ConteudoController -m Models/Artigo
```

Comment: Você está fazendo somente a injeção então no corpo tem que chamar o First().

Answer (score -3):

```
public function show(Artigo $artigo)
{
    return view('painel.revista.detalhes', ['artigo' => $artigo->first()]);
}
```

Ai conseguira acessar com `{{ $artigo->titulo }}`

Comment: Consigo acessar o registro especifico passado como parâmetro na rota do resource? Por exemplo: controller resource na chamada de show recebe um ID, minha collection consegue acessar esse registro diretamente sem ter que fazer $artigo->find...?

Answer (score -3):

Dentro do controller antes do

> $artigo = $artigo->first();

da um DD, o correto deve estar listando somente um objeto e não a collection.

Na view de listagem, você está passando somente um objeto?